# Reverse modular exponentiation : finding the base given the exponenent, the modulus semi‑prime and the result…

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Simple question, Given c=$b$<sup>$e$</sup> mod $m$, we all know finding $e$‎ is equivalent to solving the discrete logarithm.
But what about finding $b$ from c ; $e$ and the semi‑prime $m$ ? Is it something harder than factoring $m$ too ?

If yes as this is different from the ʀꜱᴀ problem, how to compute $b$ when $e$ **is more than 128‑bits long (so not small)** ? Is the possibility to set c to arbitrary values while changing prime $e$ is making things easier to get at least 1 example where $b$ is found ?

Comment: Related [Is it proven that breaking RSA is equivalent to factoring as of 2021?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/89883/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka the exponent in my case if far larger than anything used for ʀꜱᴀ and there’s to be no special cases : $c$ can be arbitrary values and $e$ too if it’s a large prime.

Comment: The only requirement for RSA's $e$ is $\textrm{gcd}(e,\lambda(m))=1$ so that the inverse exists and is unique. Choosing $e$ small is preferred to reduce the costs.

Comment: @kelalaka in my case, `e` is a random 256‒bits prime that can only be predicted, so it can’t be small. Does this makes things simpler that $gcd(e,λ(m))≥1$ which means several solutions exists ?

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to finding the RSA plaintext $b$ given the public key $(m,e)$. Usually called *The RSA Problem*. It is no harder than factoring $m$. There is however no evidence that it is easier than factoring.

*Edit:* As @DanielS points out I was a bit sloppy. For the mapping to be one-to-one, i.e., for the encryption to be reversible, we require $\textrm{gcd}(e,\lambda(m))=1$ and the term RSA problem denotes this case.

Comment: Slight quibble: it's the RSA problem when $(e,\lambda(m))=1$. Although not quite well-defined in the case $(e,\lambda(m))>1$, it is equivalent to factoring in such cases (at least in a PPT-sense for small $(p-1,q-1)$, though other results may be out there).

Comment: @kodlu even if the exponent is longer than 128‒bits large ? And if yes, how do it efficiently exactly ?

Comment: @DanielS I don’t have this in the case of the ʀꜱᴀ problem but in the case of the adaptive root problem where the random exponent can be predicted… So does the fact `e` `c` can be arbitrary values don’t change anything ? The only requirement, I have if for `e` to be a large prime. What’s $λ(m)$ ? In my case, I’m almost sure (e,λ(m)) will be greater than 1.

Comment: @user2284570: $λ$ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function). If $m=p\,q$ with $p$ and $q$ distinct primes, then $λ(n)=\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$, and $b=c^{(e^{-1}\bmodλ(n))}\bmod m$. In python (3.8 or better): `b=pow(c,pow(e,-1,math.lcm(p-1,q-1)),m)`. Or `b=pow(c,pow(e,-1,m-p-q+1),m)`. Update: that's for $\gcd(e,\lambda(m))=1$. For $\gcd(e,\lambda(m))>1$ there might be several, or no solution.

Comment: @fgrieu-modelectiontime so this requires to factorize $m$?

Comment: @user2284570: As far as we know, yes the most efficient general method is to factor $m$, for arbitrary $c$, $m$, and $e$ coprime to $p-1$ and to $q-1$. Update: If $e$ is a large prime and not chosen with knowledge of the factorization of $m$, then it's extremely likely that $e$ is coprime to $p-1$ and to $q-1$, equivalently that $\gcd(e,\lambda(m))=1$.

Comment: @DanielS but as far I m aware in the rsa problem, the base have to not be larger than the modulus which isn t the case here. Does this change anything?